# Retrieve public render parameter from OrignalParameterMap in renderRequest

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

I have passed a render parameter from one portlet to another using user friendly url navigation.

```
response.setRenderParameter("params", renderParams);
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("/wps/myportal/Home/abcPortlet"), "params");
```

Here `Home` and `abcPortlet` are user friendly page names for specific pages.

While debugging I found that `OriginalParameterMap` contains the render parameter in its URL.

Can someone tell me how to retrieve it? As usual getter methods are not able to retrieve that value.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass `render parameters` from one portlet to another. It has to be Pubic Render Parameter (PRP). The approach of setting PRP is same as that of render parameter, but both portlets should agree that, they support that PRP. For that you need to register the supported PRPs in `portlet.xml` file of both the portlets. Please refer to this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0809_hepper/0809_hepper.html) for more info.This is what the specification insist. Imagine a scenario where in we have multiple portlets from various vendors on a portal page. It is a security concern if one portlet could retrieve the parameters from the URL even if it is not targeted to that portlet.

Another approach (which is not recommended) is to type case the `RenderRequest` to `HttpServletRequest` and get the parameter from request. It is not mentioned in the specification that `PortletRequest` should be a `HttpServletRequest`. So it is better not to do that. Future implementation of Portal can change this.

Third approach is to use the URL Generation APIs and construct the URL which has the parameters targeting the portlet. You can refer to the below link which has some helper classes. This will simplify your job. [Advanced URL Generation Helper Classes](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21351642)

The best way is to use PRP. Both the source portlet and target portlet are loosely coupled.

Comment: The problem that i am facing with PRP is that it does not work between different pages. suppose we have two portlet each on different page. In this case how can we navigate between portlets with PRP? I am using IBM websphere Portal 7

Comment: How are you doing the redirection.You cannot do the redirection in Action phase using response.sendRedirect('URL'). It will not have the PRP parameters.I can share you the code if required.

Comment: That's what i am not getting how to navigate in that case with PRP. there should be something like wiring for events.
Please share the code if u can.

Comment: Please refer to this Thread. The last answer is posted by me. Hope that helps.http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=335737

Comment: I have worked on this approach but i believe its more of url generation even if we do not use PRP then also it will work.

Comment: Here we just require to send a parameter map in this case. we are not setting any render Parameter in this case.

Comment: These are PRPs, this Map contains the PRP name and their value.